# Android 4.3: Spellchecker: Disable red underline without disabling typeahead suggestions

Tags: android, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I have an EditText in which the user can type freeform text, alongside programmatically created Spannable tokens that the user can delete but not modify.

Unfortunately, these tokens still get spell checked and underlined, even though my app does not let the user modify them. They do not contain English words.

Is there a way to turn off this new red underline?
Is there a way to turn off this new red underline only for certain text spans?

Adding the textNoSuggestions flag to the android:inputType field turns off the red line on 4.3, but also turns off the spelling suggestions that appear above the keyboard as the user types, which I want to keep. On 4.1 this flag does not disable spelling suggestions.

Thanks!